# Could someone deconstruct this sentence and explain where it is right or wrong grammatically?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, modifiers, compound-adjectives

The sentence is:

> I'm of the fuck covid opinion.

A friend of mine stated it and I would like to know if someone could explain why it should or should not be written differently.

Comment: @niamulbengali It's just the punctuation. Compare: *“I’m of the ‘Screw that idea’ opinion.”*

Comment: @tchrist, indeed, it's just the punctuation, but isn't that really the answer to the question? For that matter, doesn't tagging this question as one about compound adjectives, essentially amount to answering it?

Comment: @jsw29 If does not explain the grammar as requested. Do please feel free.

Comment: 'Be of the X opinion' is an idiom. X must modify 'opinion'; it is often 'former' etc, though it is sometimes spelled out ("I'm of the _repainting yearly works out cheapest_ opinion").

Answer (score 2):

It's an instance of the general form

> I'm of the X opinion

which means about the same thing as

> My opinion is X

Inverting the sentence tends to emphasize the opinion.